# How to properly organize running multiple processes of a project

Tags: linux

I have a project for which I need to start multiple services such as webserver, websocket server, different processors of raw info into more complex etc.

Before I was doing this manually, in linux screens, but the number of the processes grew and I felt this was wrong.

I wonder if there is a proper way, a common practice how to do this in order not to miss something - forget to start one of the processes and be aware when something fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a process watcher like **[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit)** that allows you to [group processes](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-GROUPS) and create [service dependencies](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-DEPENDENCIES).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with start scripts for the init system of your distribution, e.g. `/etc/init.d` scripts or `systemd` services.